# If you build something valuable at a hackathon, who owns it?

Tags: ownership

**Foreword:** One could argue this question would be more at home on Law SE, but considering most lawyers aren't even aware of what a hackathon is, this question has a far greater chance of being properly answered here. If you disagree with that judgement, definitely let me know.

**Now onto the good stuff**

I personally love hackathons. They're a chance to develop some of the most useful skills in programming, like teamwork, rapid debugging, problem simplification, sleep deprivation tolerance, and that ability to turn an idea into a usable product as quickly and efficiently as possible. And yet there's something nagging at me: at some of the bigger hackathons, genuinely great ideas come about, ideas that could seriously be worth something. For example, Techcrunch Disrupt SF produced BlazingDB, a means of running very expensive database queries through GPUs, which is fairly genius considering any query on a distributed database is basically already a map-reduce operation, and that's just one name from the first hackathon I thought to google.

**So who owns the products produced at a hackathon? The host? The creators? The sponsors?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: FYI blazingdb was not built at a hackathon. It was a horrifying painful process of sleepless nights and mediocre wages for years before it became a product. We competed in the battledfield at disrupt. But it was not made during a hackathon

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 2):

This will be subject to the terms of conditions that you agree on when you join a hackathon. I for example will join a 2 day innovation hackathon next week and had to obey to the rules stated in the **confirmation of participation policy**.

It should usually look like this:

**Confirmation of participation**
I confirm my participation in the '*NAME OF HACKATHON*' event on '*DATE and VENUE*'. I understand that all outputs created at the above hackathon event will be on the basis of the '*NAME of LICENCE*' as detailed at '*WEBSITE WHERE TO FIND*'. By participating in this hackathon event, I hereby give permission to '*HOST NAME*' to use any pictures and videos taken during the event that include myself for the purposes of organization promotional material and publications.

Mine used the following license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode